# ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package django

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-import

I'm writing a site on Django and faced the problem that when relative importing from a directory located in the same directory as the directory in which the import is carried out, the following error appears:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

here is my import,which is in the file ***online_book/shop-cart/cart.py***

```
from ..books.models import Book
```

the Book model is in the file ***online-book/books/models.py***

[image: it`s my project structure]

help me find solution to this problem please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imports are relative to where the `manage.py` is 
so your import should be like this:

```
from books.models import Book
```

Answer (score 1):

Set dir online_book as root directory in  settings. It's *File -> Settings -> Project -> Project structure*
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).